# Can BERT output be fixed in shape, irrespective of string size?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am confused about using huggingface BERT models and about how to make them yield a prediction at a fixed shape, regardless of input size (i.e., input string length).

I tried to call the tokenizer with the parameters `padding=True, truncation=True, max_length = 15`, but the prediction output dimensions for `inputs = ["a", "a"*20, "a"*100, "abcede"*20000]` are not fixed. What am I missing here?

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

inputs = ["a", "a"*20, "a"*100, "abcede"*20000]
for input in inputs:
  inputs = tokenizer(input, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length = 15, return_tensors="pt")
  outputs = model(**inputs)
  print(outputs.last_hidden_state.shape, input, len(input))
```

output:

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased were not used when initializing BertModel: ['cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
torch.Size([1, 3, 768]) a 1
torch.Size([1, 12, 768]) aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 20
torch.Size([1, 15, 768]) aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 100
torch.Size([1, 3, 768]) abcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcededeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeab....deabbcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcede 120000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the tokenizer with only one sentence and `padding=True`, `truncation=True`, `max_length = 15`, it will pad the output sequence to the longest input sequence and truncate if required. Since you are providing only one sentence, the tokenizer can not pad anything because it is already the longest sequence of the batch. That means you can achieve what you want in two ways:

1. Provide a batch:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
 
  tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
  model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
   
  inputs = ["a", "a"*20, "a"*100, "abcede"*200]
  inputs = tokenizer(inputs, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length = 15, return_tensors="pt")
  print(inputs["input_ids"])
  outputs = model(**inputs)
  print(outputs.last_hidden_state.shape)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[  101,  1037,   102,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0],
        [  101, 13360, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057,
          2050,   102,     0,     0,     0],
        [  101, 13360, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057,
         11057, 11057, 11057, 11057,   102],
        [  101,   100,   102,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0]])
torch.Size([4, 15, 768])
```

2. Set `padding="max_length"`:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

inputs = ["a", "a"*20, "a"*100, "abcede"*200]
for i in inputs:
  inputs = tokenizer(i, padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length = 15, return_tensors="pt")
  print(inputs["input_ids"])
  outputs = model(**inputs)
  print(outputs.last_hidden_state.shape, i, len(i))
```

Output:

```py
tensor([[ 101, 1037,  102,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
            0,    0,    0]])
torch.Size([1, 15, 768]) a 1
tensor([[  101, 13360, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057,
          2050,   102,     0,     0,     0]])
torch.Size([1, 15, 768]) aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 20
tensor([[  101, 13360, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057, 11057,
         11057, 11057, 11057, 11057,   102]])
torch.Size([1, 15, 768]) aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 100
tensor([[101, 100, 102,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
           0]])
torch.Size([1, 15, 768]) abcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcedeabcede 1200
```

Answer (score 0):

BERT is producing an embedding for every token, and your input strings are generating different number of tokens.  (I don't know why the last string is producing so few, that's kind of odd.)

If you want to get a single embedding for the whole input text from this model, there are two ways depending on how it was trained:

1. If one of the tasks the model was trained on was e.g. next sentence prediction, you should take the embedding of whatever token was fed into that task.  This is usually either the first or the last one.  So `outputs.last_hidden_state[:, 0. :]` or `outputs.last_hidden_state[:, -1, :]`.
2. If that isn't true, you should probably just take the mean of all the token embeddings.  Something like `np.mean(outputs.last_hidden_state, axis=1)`.

I don't actually know how the model you're using was trained, so I can't say which of those is best.

I'd recommend just using a model that's meant to embed whole sentences at once though, such as the models at https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html .

Comment: The sentence transformers are just ordinary transformers that have a pretraining objective to produce meaningful sentence embeddings. That means you can compare the sentence embeddings of two sentences and calculate similarity for example. You can do the same with an ordinary BERT except that the output will be garbage for sentence similarity tasks.

Comment: The last string produces only one `[UNK]` token because BERT uses a workpiece tokenizer and could not find a split strategy for this string.